# find a directories that does not contain a file with name OSZICAR and then cd into that directory and do something more

Tags: find

I would like to find directories that does not contain a file with name OSZICAR and then cd into that directory and do something more...

all i have now is:

```
find `pwd` -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c "echo {}; cd {}; ls; if [! -f $0/OSZICAR];echo "doing my thing";fi" \;
```

but there is error, could anyone help? Thank you

My original command without the Criteria of Not having OSZICAR is:

```
find `pwd` -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c "echo {}; cd {}; ls; cp ../../submit_script_Stampede.sh .; ls;sed -i s/Monkhorst/Gamma/ KPOINTS; cp CONTCAR POSCAR ;sbatch submit_script_Stampede.sh" \;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for dir in $(find ${PWD} -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d)
do
  cd ${dir}
  ls OSZICAR > /dev/null 2>&1; r=${?}
  if [ ${r} -ne 0 ]
  then 
    # do your thing here
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks... seems no easier way to just directly incorporate to one find command:)

Comment: There is a possibility of making it a one liner but it just complicates the process in my opinion. Type these lines on a command prompt one by one. Execute it and then recall the line by up arrow (using bash I assume). You will see the one liner version. If you want to make an alias or something, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `[` and `]` are space separated and remove the " around the argument for the `echo` command or replace those " by \". Also note that {} must be a separate argument.

So a corrected command would be:

```
find `pwd` -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo $1; cd $1; ls; if [ ! -f OSZICAR ];then echo "doing my thing";fi' dummy {} \;
```

Comment: Still having a error: dummy: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
dummy: -c: line 0: `echo $1; cd $1; ls; if [ ! -f OSZICAR ];echo "doing my thing";fi'

Comment: OK added a `then`. Whether this does what you like is still not clear but it lists all directories.